# Cropping a string

Tags: c

I have a buffer that looks like this:

```
char *buffer;
```

The content of the buffer looks like this:

```
apple; apple fruit \t data \n
apple tree \t data \n
apple pie \t data \n
Holland; Netherlands; The Netherlands '\t' data \n
....
```

I want to search for one of those words.

I can find the word in the buffer. However, if I am looking for apple I end up getting from apple to the end of the buffer, all the lines below apple. It just discards everything above. So I want to cut out at the end of data when I hit \n.

I tried this:

```
   // find the word.
char *found = strstr(buffer, word);

// try to keep the line containing the word and the data 
// but discard everything after '\n'
found = strchar(found, '\n');
*(found +1) = 0;

printf(found);
```

Then when I try to printf I don't print anything at all. So when I run `strchar` I ruin everything. If I comment out the `strchar` part I can see my word and definition + everything else left in the buffer.

Comment: `*(found +1) = '\0';` Try NULL terminating it.

Comment: @erbdex That is exactly the same thing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, the compiler generates the same code. But with a='x' I read that I assign a character. With a='\0' I read that I assign a character (value is 0) to a variable that holds a character but no index. With a=0 I must think about what's a? So it's the same code but not exactly the same thing as Christopher wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you *change* `found` to point at the newline you find, meaning that `found` points to the part of the string that contain the newline and the terminator. You need to use a different variable for that.

Comment: Any tip on how I can re-apply it so I only get the data after '\t'?  I did something like this `char *t = strchr(found, '\t');`

Answer (score 0):

If you set `*(found+1)=0` and then call `printf(found)`, you are calling `printf` with a string of length zero. Not seeing any output is the expected behavior in this case.

Maybe you meant to say `printf(buffer)`?